# Where do I put Jar files in Lucee?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

I have moved from Railo to Lucee, this particular jar file had resided in /railo/lib, and I placed it in what I thought the lucee equivalent which was to /lucee/lib and it is not picking it up, as in I get this error:

> cannot load class through its string name, because no definition for
>   the class with the specified name [com.notnoop.apns.APNS] could be
>   found

When trying to load via:

```
createObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.APNS")
```

Which worked on the railo installation. I also notice that /lucee/lib only has one jar file whilst /rail/lib had many. Where should my jar file go, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install Lucee, and what version is it?

Comment: I do not have an answer about the base path, but does not Lucee also support dynamic loading from an arbitrary file path ie `createObject("java", "package.ClassName", "c:/path/to/someFile1.jar,c:/path/to/someFile2.jar");`?

Answer (score 4):

So this is an easy fix.  You'll want to locate the folder that your current site is in.  Whether that be on a linux based or windows based machine...you'll want to copy the .jar file to the /WEB-INF/lucee/lib/ directory in the root of your site.  Restart Lucee and you should be in business.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And what if you are using commandbox? With command box, you can start a CF site anywhere but there isn't a web-inf folder.

Comment: Oh you should! but I digress. I found out all you have to do just add `component {
    this.name = "MyApplication";
 this.javaSettings = { loadPaths = ["C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lucee\lib\jsoup-1.12.1.jar"] };
    // ... more application settings
}` to your Application.cfc and restart the web server.